# How to avoid calling a api in loops?

Tags: python, api, http, request

I make several python programs that need to loop every 5 seconds to check via a public api if the data has evolved.
Is there a solution to be "contacted" by the api when there is a change to avoid unnecessary requests that return unmodified data.

Example :
If the api returns x=12 and x=12 during 10 minutes is it possible to receive a "signal" in order to send a request only 10 minutes passed to obtain the new value of x and don't send few requests with same response

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming that the API is a web API over HTTP.

HTTP requests work the way that it is always the client that queries the server.

**Assuming that you have control over the API there are the following solutions**

From a server perspective you can solve it by having the API using [webhooks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook)
to inform the server when data has changed

From a client perspective you'd either look into [long polling](https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-http-long-polling), or maintaining some sort of bidrectional communication protocol with the server where the server can notify the client of any new updates.
You could look into [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API)

Comment: Important to note for the OP's purposes (using an existing public API), this is something that would have to be provided by the existing API

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Very good point - I added it in the answer

Comment: I'll do some research on this, thanks for your help!